# How to add contents of file to MySQL query inside php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm using the following php query to install tables in my CMS system:

```
$q=new mysql("
INSERT INTO `adm` (`id`, `login`, `adm`, `passwd`, `czas`, `logged`, `ip`, `email`) VALUES
(0, 'admin', 1, PASSWORD('admin'), 0, 0, '0.0.0.0', 'admin@domain.com');
");
```

However instead of e-mail admin@domain.com I would like to use e-mail stored inside `/settings/contact.inc.php` file which is:

```
    <?php    
$emailaddress='admin@domain.com';
    ?>
```

Comment: Storing file in a db is a bad idea, store it in filesystem and store a path in the db

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to do :)

Comment: @zerkms, i dont think he want to save file in db. Seems like he only want to read variable from another php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use it like,

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `adm` (`id`, `login`, `adm`, `passwd`, `czas`, `logged`, `ip`, `email`) 
          VALUES (0, 'admin', 1, PASSWORD('admin'), 0, 0, '0.0.0.0', '$emailaddress')";
```

**Note:** You need to include `/settings/contact.inc.php` file.

**Do Read:** [sql injection attacks](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)! Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this post. @Rikesh is right you need to include this file and use assigned variable before the query +1 from me.

Comment: @RobertPodwika - Thanks. It's always feel bad to get down voted without any comment :p

Comment: N/P I often get downvoted for good answer without any comment so I understand you ;)

Comment: @Rikesh I'd downvote, but since you're asking for a reason *why* anyone would downvote, consider this. The person asking the question might not know much about PHP/MySQL (since he or she had problem concatinating a string), yet you're showing him or her that it's good practise to just paste a variable in the middle of an SQL query. In a couple of months, this person will copy paste the same piece of code and create SQL injections all over the place (even though they were originally just meant to be from a static file, where no injection should occur).

Comment: @h2ooooooo but this variable is set by him not by a user so attacker cannot modify it. Of course it is better to use prepared statements but it doesn't look like problem here.

Comment: @RobertPodwika As my comment said, the user is in the phase of programming where everything is new. Next time said user needs to input a variable into an SQL query, he'll just copy paste the same piece of code used here, not considering injections (why should he? No one told him about them). A sensible answer would say "But please note that you should only do this if you're sure there's no injection in the email, and don't use this with dynamic strings".

Answer (score 3):

Simply include the file and use the variable:

```
require_once("/settings/contact.inc.php");

$q=new mysql("
INSERT INTO `adm` (`id`, `login`, `adm`, `passwd`, `czas`, `logged`, `ip`, `email`) VALUES
(0, 'admin', 1, PASSWORD('admin'), 0, 0, '0.0.0.0', '$emailaddress');
");
```

**Beware of SQL injection**

In this case you know where `$emailaddress`, comes from and you can trust the content. In other cases you need to protect your code against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Therefore, I advise you to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), using the [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions.

You can then replace the variables in the query by a question-mark or named placeholder:

```
"INSERT INTO `adm` (`id`, `login`, `adm`, `passwd`, `czas`, `logged`, `ip`, `email`) VALUES (0, 'admin', 1, PASSWORD('admin'), 0, 0, '0.0.0.0', ?);"
```

and bind `$emailaddress` using the [mysqli_stmt_bind_param](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the /settings/contact.inc.php and then you can use the $emailaddress variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
include('/settings/contact.inc.php');
$q=new mysql("INSERT INTO `adm` (`id`, `login`, `adm`, `passwd`, `czas`, `logged`, `ip`, `email`) VALUES (0, 'admin', 1, PASSWORD('admin'), 0, 0, '0.0.0.0', '$emailaddress');");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include the file and then you can use the all variable like below.

```
<?php include_once('/settings/contact.inc.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers was great so i voted up all of them. Besides that way that everyone suggested you can do it by using `fopen` and `fread`. I know that way is simple way, but my way is just another way.

```
$filePath = './settings/contact.inc.php';

$handle  = fopen($filePath,"r+");
$content = fread($handle,filesize($filePath));
$array = explode(" ",$content);
foreach($array as $word)
{
    if(filter_var($word, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $emailaddress = $word;
    }
}
fclose($handle);

$q=new mysql("INSERT INTO `adm` (`id`, `login`, `adm`, `passwd`, `czas`, `logged`, `ip`, `email`) 
VALUES
(0, 'admin', 1, PASSWORD('admin'), 0, 0, '0.0.0.0', '$emailaddress');");
```

Comment: In case you're serious about this answer, I would prefer a regular expression